# Error closing a JDBC child wrapper: com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.StaleConnectionException: Closed Connection

Tags: jdbc, websphere, websphere-8

Getting Stale: closed connection error while trying to connect with the database.

```
[5/13/21 8:24:30:442 CDT] 00000583 ThreadMonitor W   WSVR0606W: Thread "ORB.thread.pool : 0" (00000583) was previously reported to be hung but has completed.  It was active for approximately 900827 milliseconds.  There is/are 0 thread(s) in total in the server that still may be hung.
[5/13/21 8:24:30:441 CDT] 0000ad9b WSJdbcConnect W   DSRA8650W: Error closing a JDBC child wrapper, com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement@51fcce3e
com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.StaleConnectionException: Closed Connection
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor42150.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437)
    at com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.GenericDataStoreHelper.mapExceptionHelper(GenericDataStoreHelper.java:630)
    at com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.GenericDataStoreHelper.mapException(GenericDataStoreHelper.java:689)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.AdapterUtil.mapException(AdapterUtil.java:2289)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcUtil.mapException(WSJdbcUtil.java:1219)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.closeWrapper(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:565)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcObject.close(WSJdbcObject.java:242)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcObject.close(WSJdbcObject.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcObject.closeChildWrappers(WSJdbcObject.java:297)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.dissociate(WSJdbcConnection.java:1951)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.dissociateConnections(WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.java:1255)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.MCWrapper.cleanup(MCWrapper.java:1870)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.release(PoolManager.java:2975)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.MCWrapper.releaseToPoolManager(MCWrapper.java:2684)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.MCWrapper.abortMC(MCWrapper.java:4086)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.AbortableXATransactionWrapper.abort(AbortableXATransactionWrapper.java:58)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RegisteredResources.abort(RegisteredResources.java:3268)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.abortTransactionParticipants(TransactionImpl.java:3308)
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.timeoutTransaction(TransactionImpl.java:1301)
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TimeoutManager$TimeoutInfo.alarm(TimeoutManager.java:225)
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.util.alarm.AlarmManagerImpl$AlarmListenerAdapter.alarm(AlarmManagerImpl.java:48)
    at com.ibm.ejs.util.am._Alarm.runImpl(_Alarm.java:151)
    at com.ibm.ejs.util.am._Alarm.run(_Alarm.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909)
```

What could be the possible reason of getting stale/closed connection error in the WebSphere logs?

Answer (score 0):

The stack shows that it is processing a transaction timeout, which includes aborting the participating connection.  Notice that the warning message immediately before it (WSVR0606W) shows that an operation that was thought to be hung has finally just completed after 15 minutes (900 seconds).  This is likely not a coincidence.  Possibly the abort processing has allowed that operation to continue, and if both threads proceed to close out the connection simultaneously, you can see an error like this because the other thread managed to do so first which was the other thread wasn't expecting.  JDBC connections aren't well designed to be accessed on multiple threads, but Connection.abort makes that possible.  The bigger issue to be concerned with is why you have an operation -- possibly a transactional operation -- taking 15 minutes or more to run.  I'd focus on fixing that first.  If, however, a 15+ minute transaction is truly expected, then you need to be increasing the transaction timeout to avoid timing it out and aborting it.

Comment: So what I can infer is that, two threads were running the same transaction and both wanted to close the connection but because the other closed it first which the 1st one wasn't expecting led to this issue?

Comment: One of the threads would have been running the transaction, and the other aborting it after it timed out. (This is an educated guess/hypothesis, you can't know for certain from just 2 messages).  I would say that the some operation within the transaction taking too long is likely the underlying cause of it.  So if you can fix the cause of the first warning, it should also resolve the second.